# S3 CORS not working with JQuery Ajax request in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cors

I have the following S3 bucket: http://my-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

I have added a CORS configuration, as per http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html :

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
<AllowedHeader>x-requested-with</AllowedHeader>
 <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://*.test.com</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I make an AJAX Post request to my bucket using jquery (note, origin is jd.test.com:8000):

```
$.ajax('http://my-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/', {
    type: "POST",
    data: $(":hidden", self).serializeArray(),
    files: $(":file", self),
    statusCode: {
      204: function(){
        //do something
      }
    }
});
```

Upon making the request, my chrome console complains:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my-bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/. Origin http://www.jd.test.com:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Any help as to why the POST request is not being made would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a simple tutorial, it uses rails, but it could easily be translated for any other server framework.
The upload is handled by the awesome [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).
And [Direct upload to s3 with cors](https://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3).

Answer (score 2):

Your CORSConfiguration must contain the port number, because the port number is part of the origin, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Even when AllowedOrigin is *?

Comment: In this case yes, because the first rule with the "*" is not relevant! The ajax request to jd.test.com:8000 does not have an "x-requested-with"  header (or is that something that jquery adds automatically?). Therefore, the first rule does not apply. The second rule does not apply either, because here, the AllowedOrigin doesnt match. So, none of your rules says "yes" and therefore the request is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to dive into this as well. Have you tried changing AllowedMethod to PUT? File uploads are done using PUT not POST.

--edit

Silly me. I'm getting 403 forbidden with PUT requests. POST requests give a 400 status code.

Comment: Hi. It seems that chrome was blocking my request from being made, so the problem was probably client side. I played around with the Javascript code a bit, and found that manually adding a `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` header (using the $.ajax() beforeSend callback) stopped Chrome from blocking my request. However, finding a workaround for this just led me to other, bigger, problems. So I'm no longer pursuing this approach.

Comment: But do let me know if you have any success uploading files using cors !

Comment: @Himerzi Where do you put the XML CORS code in relation to your HTML page? I'd like to help you but don't know XML at all. Also, what are these "other, bigger problems" you speak of? Again, I'd like to help if possible.

Comment: @timpeterson The XML CORS code lives on the server, not the HTML page. The bigger problem is that AJAX file uploads aren't supported by JQuery.They are supported by HTML5, however I couldn't find a plugin/easy way of taking advantage of this, and there appear to be some i.e. compatibility issues. Implementing this myself, in a manner that supports i.e. + other browsers, appears to not be a trivial task.

Comment: it looks like jQuery can do CORS, just google it and you'll find lots of demos. Though I agree being compatible with older browsers seem like a serious problem. I'm using this [really nice jQuery file upload plugin which supports CORS](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) but just don't understand how to use it to do the S3-CORS connection yet. Could help you with other parts of this plugin if you're interested though.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by setting the `AllowedHeader` field to `*` in my CORS configuration on the S3 bucket.

Here's my complete CORS S3 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```